# Angular 9 PrimeNg how to style p-table border color?

Tags: angular, frontend, primeng, angular9, primeng-datatable

How can i change the border color of p-table? I was able to change table header border color of the table but i don't know how to change the color of the body of the p-table.

- `body .ui-table .ui-table-tbody > tr > td { padding: 0.571em 0.857em; border: #e3e3e3; }`

I have tried this in theme.css at resources/rhea/theme.css in primeng but its still no use help.

Answer (score 0):

`body .ui-table .ui-table-tbody > tr > td { border: 1px solid #dadada; }`

Found it! Just find this and simply change border: 1px solid #dadada to transparent